# Tidy up multiple identical commit messages

Tags: git

I have a program that can generate a number of identical commit messages e.g

```
cd204a0 Auto - running enum_spec.rb:17
78c3a8a Auto - running enum_spec.rb:17
d0021dd Auto - running enum_spec.rb:17
901a01b Auto - running enum_spec.rb:17
```

I would like to automatically rebase all these identical commit messages into one commit message, but still be able to checkout any of the shas.  I also would only do this automatic rebasing up the point of my last push to origin.  Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: You can't do this.  If you squash down these four commits into just one commit, then you'll have just a single logical commit with that message, but three of the commits will cease to be in your branch.  Actually, all four will cease to exist, because the fourth commit will be rewritten into something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Tim Biegeleisen's comment:

'You can't do this. If you squash down these four commits into just one commit, then you'll have just a single logical commit with that message, but three of the commits will cease to be in your branch. Actually, all four will cease to exist, because the fourth commit will be rewritten into something else.'